# Timer and keybinding at the same time

Tags: java, swing, timer, count

So basically i use a keybinding on a jpanel to start a timer. I am trying to figure out how to use the keybinding again but while the timer is still going in order to increase the count.

```
m2.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke
(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT,0,true),"left");
    m2.getActionMap().put("left",new Actions());


public void Timer(boolean startTimer){
    if(startTimer==true){
        long staTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(startTimer==true){
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000.0-staTime/1000.0);
        }
    }
}

public class Actions extends AbstractAction {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
int start = 0;
int count = 0;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Begin b = new Begin();
        if(start==0){   
            start++;
            b.Timer(true);
        }
        count++;
        System.out.println(count);
        if(count==10){
            b.Timer(false);
        }

}
```

Comment: You do realise  the moment you start the timer, you'll block the event dispatching thread and cause your program to come to a complete stock...

Comment: Ya I know im trying to figure out how to keep the timer going without blocking the dispatch thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what that code is trying to do. It looks like you are tying to create your own Timer. Well, Swing already has a Timer class so don't reinvent the wheel.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information. The Swing Timer API also has methods that allow you to dynamically change the interval at which the Timer fires.

The Timer example in the tutorial is relatively complex. Here is a simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerTime extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private JLabel timeLabel;

    public TimerTime()
    {
        timeLabel = new JLabel( new Date().toString() );
        add( timeLabel );

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.setInitialDelay(1);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //System.out.println(e.getSource());
        timeLabel.setText( new Date().toString() );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TimerTime");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TimerTime() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```